# Communicate from a C++ DLL to a running C# programm

Tags: c#, c++, dll, metatrader4

I just implemented a C++ DLL into Metatrader 4.

In this DLL, a function is occasionally called by Metatrader. This function gets values from Metatrader and should pass it a C# program which is already running.

What's the proper way to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

- socket
- window message
- pipe
- I am sure there are many other ways

Answer (score 0):

The topic you're looking for is IPC, Interprocess Communication. MSDN has a guide on the subject: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To copy their list of methods,

- Clipboard
- COM
- Data Copy
- DDE
- File Mapping
- Mailslots
- Pipes
- RPC
- Windows Sockets